# SimpleForm 3 initializer for Bootstrap4 beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, bootstrap-4

The current Bootstrap 4 beta adds error class attributes directly to the input tag like this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label for="validationServer03">City</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer03" placeholder="City" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid city.
  </div>
</div>
```

SimpleForm however, adds the class to the field wrapper. Is there any way to change the initializer so it adds an error class to the input field instead of the field wrapper?

Comment: I've looked into this and it seems currently it's not supported, however, there is a PR which would bring this feature in: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/1476

Comment: Here is a workaround for the time being; https://gist.github.com/anlek/50e2e464cdfef44a86f105210e76dcca